# 'Failed to cast object' System.String [] 'to type' System.IConvertible '.'

Tags: c#, windows

I need to read the numbers in the txt file in listBox and convert it to numbers. But I get an error ---> 'Failed to cast object' System.String [] 'to type' System.IConvertible '.' what can I do? I am using C # windows application.
Thanks.

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\Numbers\\numbers.txt");

        for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
        {
            var fields = lines[i].Split(' ');
            Convert.ToInt32(fields);
            listBox1.Items.Add(fields);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Split()` gives you an array. You can't convert a whole array into numbers. Use a loop to iterate through the fields and add them to the listbox.

Also, you need to use the return value of `Convert.ToInt32()` (actually, when you assign it to a listbox, it will be converted to a string again).

Comment: But then I need to get an array of those numbers, and arrange it in order. That's why I used Split ().

Comment: Yes, I didn't say you should remove Split(). I said "Use a loop to iterate through the fields"

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to convert string to int in order to add it to listbox items and you doing it wrong way. Just remove this line from your code

```
 Convert.ToInt32(fields);
```

and your code should be

```
List<string> items= new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
{
 var fields = lines[i].Split(' ');
 items.AddRange(fields);
}
ListBox1.Items.AddRange(items);
```

Comment: I removed it, but I got a "string [] Array" on every line in the listBox.